# Can not get wireless to work

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

```
#iwconfig

usb0      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

#ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether ec:f4:bb:74:5f:f9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 28  bytes 1596 (1.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28  bytes 1596 (1.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.42.169  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
        inet6 fe80::f076:3aff:fe0d:f215  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f2:76:3a:0d:f2:15  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10723  bytes 9294838 (8.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9929  bytes 1471536 (1.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

#rfkill
Usage:  rfkill [options] command
Options:
    --version   show version (0.5-1+b1 (Debian))
Commands:
    help
    event
    list [IDENTIFIER]
    block IDENTIFIER
    unblock IDENTIFIER
where IDENTIFIER is the index no. of an rfkill switch or one of:
    <idx> all wifi wlan bluetooth uwb ultrawideband wimax wwan gps fm nfc


#lspci -knn | grep Net -A202:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

I have read a lot and still I can not get anywhere with this. I can not even see wireless option in my network connections. I never had such trouble with linux and wifi in the past and just installed kali where parrot os was working well on this machine. What am I missing and why isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the wifi working on kali linux using the BCM43142 wifi card , you should install the `linux-headers` package and the `broadcom-sta-dkms`

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
reboot
```

Then

```
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
modprobe wl
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks GAD3R. I had attempted updating and upgrading before posting, but with no luck. Apparently in my endeavors, I did something that allowed me to update and upgrade this time. Works like a charm now and with out all the runarounds I have come across on the forums.